# Updating two text objects in JavaFX, one field after another, only seeing final result of both changes

Tags: javafx

I have three text fields displayed, and I want to change the second one, see the result on the display (so wait a couple of seconds), then change the third one, and see the result on the display. Instead, I only see the result of both changes on the display (with no pause inbetween).

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.animation.PauseTransition;
import javafx.util.Duration;
import javafx.scene.Scene; 
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;

public class TestApp extends Application
{
    private Text tone = new Text("one");
    private Text ttwo = new Text("two");
    private Text tthree = new Text("three");

    private void process()
    {
        PauseTransition pauseTransition = new PauseTransition(Duration.seconds(2));
        pauseTransition.setOnFinished(event -> ttwo.setText("four"));
        pauseTransition.play();

        pauseTransition = new PauseTransition(Duration.seconds(2));
        pauseTransition.setOnFinished(event -> tthree.setText("five"));
        pauseTransition.play();
   } // end of method "process"

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) 
    {
        VBox vboxRoot = new VBox();
        vboxRoot.getChildren().add(tone);
        vboxRoot.getChildren().add(ttwo);
        vboxRoot.getChildren().add(tthree);
        Scene myScene = new Scene(vboxRoot,350,350);
        stage.setScene(myScene);
        stage.setTitle("Test");
        stage.show();
        process();
    } // end of method "start"

} // end of class "TestApp"
```

So initially

```
one
two
three
```

is displayed; followed by

```
one
four
five
```

What I want to see is

```
one
four
three
```

a pause and then

```
one
four
five
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if its a typo if your `What I want to see is` but if its not the reason you are getting

```
one
two 
three
```

to initially display is because thats what you have them set as and in this piece of code below you setup 2 `PauseTransition`s that both have a 2 second wait before changing the text

```
private void process()
{
    PauseTransition pauseTransition = new PauseTransition(Duration.seconds(2));
    pauseTransition.setOnFinished(event -> ttwo.setText("four"));
    pauseTransition.play();

    pauseTransition = new PauseTransition(Duration.seconds(2));
    pauseTransition.setOnFinished(event -> tthree.setText("five"));
    pauseTransition.play();
}
```

To fix this you can do a few things such as

1. Appropriately set what you want from the start
2. Run `ttwo.setText("four");` at the start of your `process()` method

After doing that you get the starting result of

```
one
four
three
```

and after the pause transition finishes 2 seconds later you will see

```
one
four
five
```

Answer (score 3):

After `pauseTransition.play();` you assign new value to `pauseTransition` and you  play it again, long before the first one completes.

A better approach would be :
Introduce a counter field :  `private int counter = 0;` 
And use it like so:

```
 private void process()  {

        PauseTransition pauseTransition = new PauseTransition(Duration.seconds(2));
        pauseTransition.setOnFinished(event ->{
            show(counter++);
            if(counter < 5 ) pauseTransition.play();//stop criteria 
        });
        pauseTransition.play();
   }

private void show(int counter) {
    //respond based on counter 
}
```

The following is [mcve](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366988/what-does-mcve-mean) the demonstrates the idea (it is not meant to demostrate the exact behavior you want which is not clear to me) :

```
import javafx.animation.PauseTransition;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class FxMain extends Application {

    private int counter = 0;
    private final Text tone = new Text("one"),
                       ttwo = new Text("two"),
                       tthree = new Text("three");

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{

        VBox root = new VBox(10);
        root.setPadding(new Insets(10));
        root.getChildren().addAll(tone,ttwo,tthree);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 100,100));
        primaryStage.sizeToScene();
        primaryStage.show();
        process();
    }

     private void process()  {

            PauseTransition pauseTransition = new PauseTransition(Duration.seconds(2));
            pauseTransition.setOnFinished(event ->{
                show(counter++);
                if(counter < 3 ) {
                    pauseTransition.play();//stop criteria
                }
            });
            pauseTransition.play();
       }

    private void show(int counter) {

        switch(counter){
             case 0:
                 tone.setText("two");
                 break;
             case 1:
                 ttwo.setText("three");
                 break;
             default :
                 tthree.setText("four");
                 break;
        }
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

---

[image]

Comment: OK thanks for that. What I'm really after is a way of updating the display (which may be more complicated than the example I've given), then pausing, before doing the next update (which again could be some other part of the display).

I realise now that by varying the time delay in the PauseTransition I could build a timeline of changes that get played once and once only. But that's not really what I'm after ... sorry if my question was unclear.

Comment: I've tried threads and Platform->runLater, but I still just jump to the final display after all the changes have been made, no pauses inbetween the changes. I'm after original display; pause;change;pause;change;pause/finish.

Comment: You do not need ` Platform->runLater` to modify gui when using javafx animation tools like `PauseTransition`. Use the code I posted and modify it to your needs.

Answer (score 2):

As others have mentioned, you play both `PauseTransition`s virtually in parallel. They are started within milliseconds (if not nanoseconds) of each other and I would not be surprised if they actually completed in the same frame. Because of this you see the result of both animations simultaneously.

One solution is to use a [`SequentialTransition`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.graphics/javafx/animation/SequentialTransition.html); it will play a list of animations in the order of said list.

```
private void process() {
    SequentialTransition st = new SequentialTransition();

    PauseTransition pauseTransition = new PauseTransition(Duration.seconds(2));
    pauseTransition.setOnFinished(event -> ttwo.setText("four"));
    st.getChildren().add(pauseTransition);

    pauseTransition = new PauseTransition(Duration.seconds(2));
    pauseTransition.setOnFinished(event -> tthree.setText("five"));
    st.getChildren().add(pauseTransition);

    st.play();
}
```

Another solution is to use a [`Timeline`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.graphics/javafx/animation/Timeline.html) made up of multiple [`KeyFrame`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.graphics/javafx/animation/KeyFrame.html)s configured to execute at increasing times.

```
private void process() {
    new Timeline(
            new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(2), event -> ttwo.setText("four")),
            new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(4), event -> tthree.setText("five"))
    ).play();
}
```

---

You [mention](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57145728/updating-two-text-fields-in-javafx-one-field-after-another-only-seeing-final-r#comment100811483_57147167) your real goal may be more complicated than setting the text properties of some `Text` objects. You can adapt either solution to a more general purpose mechanism. Here's an example for a `Timeline` that will execute an arbitrary number of actions, with a fixed delay between each action (including after the last action):

```
private static Timeline createTimeline(Duration period, Runnable... actions) {
    var frames = new ArrayList<KeyFrame>(actions.length + 1);

    var time = Duration.ZERO;
    for (var action : actions) {
        frames.add(new KeyFrame(time, event -> action.run()));
        time = time.add(period);
    }
    frames.add(new KeyFrame(time)); // adds a delay after last action

    return new Timeline(frames.toArray(KeyFrame[]::new));
}
```

> But what happens if I use your approach for one set of actions; and then move onto something else that generates another set of actions. How can I be sure the first set of actions has completed (i.e. been displayed) before I start the second set?

You can use the [`Animation#onFinished`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.graphics/javafx/animation/Animation.html#onFinishedProperty) property, in combination with a `Queue<Animation>`, to play the next `Animation` when the previous one completes.

```
private final Queue<Animation> animationQueue = ...;
private Animation currentAnimation;

private void playAnimation(Animation animation) {
    if (animation.getCycleCount() == Animation.INDEFINITE) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }

    animation.setOnFinished(event -> {
        currentAnimation = animationQueue.poll();
        if (currentAnimation != null) {
            currentAnimation.playFromStart();
        }
    });

    if (currentAnimation != null) {
        animationQueue.add(animation);
    } else {
        currentAnimation = animation;
        animation.playFromStart();
    }
}
```

Comment: Slaw, this looks great and I will certainly try it out. But what happens if I use your approach for one set of actions; and then move onto something else that generates another set of actions. How can I be sure the first set of actions has completed (i.e. been displayed) before I start the second set?

Comment: Edited my answer.

Comment: Slaw, this certainly looks like what I was after. Many thanks!